# Creating Samba share to exsiting Samba installation

Tags: ubuntu, samba

I am unfamiliar with Samba and need some help.

I have an Ubuntu server that has a folder that is being shared and can be seen on windows and requires a user name and password on the windows side. I want to be able to create another folder like it for a different user.

Samba is set up and working I just don't know how to create another folder to be shared.

Comment: There might be a graphical way to do it, but normally you would create an entry for the share in `/etc/samba/smb.conf`.

Comment: So in the smb.conf file if I add a section called   [new_share]   path = /user/home/new_share   Would I have to create a folder called new_share in the path

Comment: Yes, if that's the one you want to share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to edit the `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file with the parameters (with sudo perms).  Just adjust this to fit your needs at the bottom of the file:

```
[sharename]
    comment = Some Comment Text Here
    path = /mnt/sharedfolder/
    browseable = yes
    read only = no
    writable = yes
    guest ok = no
    create mask = 0644
    directory mask = 0700
    valid users = username
```

Depending on your samba configurations, you may need to add a user to the samba users as well with `smbpasswd -a username`, that would require "username" to be a user on the local machine first.  Also, you can space separate multiple users or even set up a guest one with an administrative user with more permissions.

I have had it work without restarting samba, but it's worth doing..

```
sudo /etc/init.d/samba restart
```

To mount this (from windows) you would need to do: `\\servername\sharename` wither `username` as the user and whatever password you have on the system.

Here is the [Samba page](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/ch09.html) for the Users/Security

Comment: thank you for your answer. This is exactly what I did and it worked.